# pcduino v1 project

Tags: 12.04

i'm doing this project i saw online a wifi video surveillance remote control robot here is the link 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/pcduino/book/Rover+-+A+WiFi+Video+Surveillance+Remote+Robot++Powered+by+pcDuino.pdf, but instead of using the pcduino as a wifi i'm using another wi-fi device for internet i think it is better. i'm having an issue trying to see the streaming video when i enter the ip address of the pcduino it says 172.20.10.2:8090/?action=stream it saying unable to connect or error unable to open the file, i don't know if i should enter the wi-fi ip address as i'm not using the board as a wifi. the other issue is when trying to compile the car test code on linux(make command) i get this error no targets specified and no makefile found. stop. 
there is no much info on the internet on how to create a makefile so i'm kind of stuck i don't know how to do that my code is inside /home/ubuntu . i decided to compile the code using the arduino IDE inside the pcduino but it giving me errors. here is the code below

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<errno.h>
#define PORT 5000

#include <core.h>
#define  servo_x      4
#define  servo_y     7
#define  cycle                 20000
#define A(x) (struct sockaddr*)(&x)

int led_pin = 2;
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
int n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
char sendBuff[1025];
time_t ticks; 

#define pinI1     8  //define IN1 interface
#define pinI2     11 //define IN2 interface 
#define speedpinA 9  //enable motor A
#define pinI3     12 //define IN3 interface 
#define pinI4     13 //define IN4 interface 
#define speedpinB 10 //enable motor B
#define spead     14//define the spead of motor
void forward()
{
     analogWrite(speedpinA,spead);//input a simulation value to set the speed
     analogWrite(speedpinB,spead);
     digitalWrite(pinI4,HIGH);//turn DC Motor B move clockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI3,LOW);
     digitalWrite(pinI2,LOW);//turn DC Motor A move anticlockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI1,HIGH);
}
void backward()
{
     analogWrite(speedpinA,spead);//input a simulation value to set the speed
     analogWrite(speedpinB,spead);
     digitalWrite(pinI4,LOW);//turn DC Motor B move anticlockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI3,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(pinI2,HIGH);//turn DC Motor A move clockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI1,LOW);
}
void left()
{
     analogWrite(speedpinA,spead);//input a simulation value to set the speed
     analogWrite(speedpinB,spead);
     digitalWrite(pinI4,HIGH);//turn DC Motor B move clockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI3,LOW);
     digitalWrite(pinI2,HIGH);//turn DC Motor A move clockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI1,LOW);
}
void right()
{
     analogWrite(speedpinA,spead);//input a simulation value to set the speed
     analogWrite(speedpinB,spead);
     digitalWrite(pinI4,LOW);//turn DC Motor B move anticlockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI3,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(pinI2,LOW);//turn DC Motor A move clockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI1,HIGH);
}
void stop()
{
     digitalWrite(speedpinA,0);// Unenble the pin, to stop the motor. this          should be done to avid damaging the motor. 
     digitalWrite(speedpinB,0);
     digitalWrite(pinI4,LOW);//turn DC Motor B move anticlockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI3,LOW);
     digitalWrite(pinI2,LOW);//turn DC Motor A move clockwise
     digitalWrite(pinI1,LOW);
}

void servo_contor(char servo_pin,int degree)
{
     //  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
     //{
       digitalWrite(servo_pin,HIGH);
       delayMicroseconds(degree);
       digitalWrite(servo_pin,LOW);
       delayMicroseconds(cycle - degree);
     //}
}

void port_init()
{
   pinMode(servo_x,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(servo_y,OUTPUT);

   pinMode(pinI1,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(pinI2,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(speedpinA,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(pinI3,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(pinI4,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(speedpinB,OUTPUT);

   servo_contor(4,1500);
   servo_contor(7,1500);
   delay(100);
}

void* func(void*p)
{
        static int x=1500;
        static int y=1500;
    int c = (int)p;
    char buf[1000];
    for(;;)
    {
    int n =     read(c,buf,sizeof(buf)-1);
    if(n<=0) break;
    buf[n] = '\0';  
    int i;
    write(1,buf,n);
    //digitalWrite(servo_x,LOW);
    //digitalWrite(servo_y,LOW);
    servo_contor(4,x);
    servo_contor(7,y);
        switch(buf[0])
        {
           case 'o' :          digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);  break;          // set the LED on
           case 'f':            digitalWrite(led_pin,LOW);    break;  // set the LED off
           case 'w':          forward();break;
           case 's':           backward() ; break;
           case 'a':           left();break;
           case 'd':           right();break;
           case 'i':             if(x<2500) x+=25; break;
           case 'k':            if(x>500)   x-=25;  break;
           case 'j':             if(y<2500) y+=25; break;
           case 'l':             if(y>500)   y-=25; break;
        }
     //     if( (buf[0]=='i') || (buf[0]=='k')  )
               // servo_contor(4,x);
        //  if( (buf[0]=='j') || (buf[0]=='l') )
               // servo_contor(7,y);
          if( (buf[0]=='w') || (buf[0]=='s') || (buf[0]=='a') || (buf[0]=='d') )
               delay(50);           
        stop();
    }
    close(c);

}

int s;
struct sockaddr_in si;  
void setup()
{    
         pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
    s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);      
    si.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si.sin_addr.s_addr =  INADDR_ANY;
    si.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if(bind(s,A(si),sizeof(si)))
    {
        printf("%s\n",strerror(errno)); exit(1);
    }
        listen(s,5);
}


void loop()
{
                port_init();
            socklen_t len = sizeof(si);
        int c = accept(s,A(si),&len);
        while(c<0);
        //welcome friend form ip,port
                char buf[100],ip[100];
        inet_ntop(si.sin_family,&si.sin_addr,ip,sizeof(ip));
        pthread_t id;
        pthread_create(&id,NULL,func,(void*)c);
        pthread_detach(id);
}
```

I will really appreciate any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you have this issue. Regarding the same I found the following:

The cause is multi layered:
- pcduino is NOT an Arduino board even if the pinout resembles an Aruino
- the name is rather misleading seems no more that an advertising gimmick
- most people look at it as a Linux board with some pins as against a microcontroller with Linux. Thus there is little interest for the MC side thus little info. As the lack of replies to your question shows.
- The IDE is not ported properly: IE you have to muck around with makefiles and manual compile.

Since I am looking for a fast microcontroller with true Arduino environment and this board is NOT one of those i did not and will not buy one. (It could be but at this stage the developers don't give a dime about porting the IDE/compile chain. If this changes in the future so will my attitude towards the product.)
Without any intent to hurt, you bought the board without researching if it is what you need/want.

If you want to make it work you'll need to learn how the compiling chain works and how makefiles are created. It is a science on its own. (Hence we use the Arduino environment.)